# Same code different git files, merging with keeping history

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

There was an existing bitbucket repo A with over 200 commits.
I downloaded the code (without .git files).
Created new repo B with all the existing code added in first commit.
Then 150 more commits on repo B.
repo A has no new commits, I worked on repo B only.
Now the requirement is a Single repo with all the code and history (if possible)
or Repo B changes as a single entry in history.
A third repo C will be fine coz dont want to risk A and B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you currently have

- The latest state of A as the first commit in B
- Lots of work on top of that, also in B

and you want to get C with

- All the history of A
- All the history of B on top of that (except of course the first commit).

Assuming that's correct, this is one way of doing it, via patches:

Get a fresh clone of A:

```
$ git clone A C
```

Check what the hash of the initial commit (with the stuff from A) in B is:

```
$ cd B
$ git log --oneline|tail -1
1234beef Initial commit
```

Still in B, export all the rest of your work as patches:

```
$ git format-patch 1234beef..HEAD
```

(this will generate a bunch of `.patch` files in B)

The import all those changes into your fresh clone of A:

```
$ cd C
$ git am ../B/*.patch
```

And you're done.

Comment: Yes, understood accurately. Thanks, let me try implementing the solution.

Comment: Could apply 30 patches but later started getting errors 'does not match index', 'patch does not apply', 'does not exist in index'. There were some files created stayed and deleted or moved later.

Comment: @Neeraj I think the method in this answer will choke with merge commits, i.e. if you have any non-linear piece of history. Try my answer, it works more reliable. I've done it myself once while ago.

Comment: Thanks very much @Ilkka the solution worked well in my case. with slight addition i.e. --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace. It is a copy paste solution due to well formatting of answer. I could not have done it without this much help as I am new to git.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [grafts](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint) and [filter-branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html). See Examples section, the example *To set a commit (which typically is at the tip of another history) to be the parent of the current initial commit* is exactly that you want to do. It is more reliable way as it allow to change all branches together and reorder history graph anyhow you like.

First you need `git clone B C`, then `cd C` and `git fetch A master`. So, your C will have commits from both repositories. Then add `<initial commit id from B> <last commit id from A>` into `.git/info/grafts` file. Then run `git filter-branch <initial commit id from B>..HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks @kan the first answer worked as I was the only one working i.e. linear history. So, I dint try this answer. This answer and your comment above might help others.

Answer (score 0):

[`git rebase -p --onto`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html) might be simplest.  Rebase's `-p` option tries to preserve merge structure, and its `--onto` permits specifying both the new base and the cut base explicitly.

So,

```
A=/path/to/original/repo
B=/path/to/your/work

git clone $B C
cd C

root=$(git rev-list --max-parents=0 master)
echo $root                                    # this should spit a single id

git fetch $A

git rev-parse $root^{tree}                    # the two outputs here 
git rev-parse FETCH_HEAD^{tree}               # ... should be equal

git rebase -p --onto FETCH_HEAD $root master  # if both the above are true, bingo
```