# git rebase without merging any changes

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

Imagine we have two repositories in which the same piece of software is being developed. One being the legacy version that is shipped to customers, bugs are getting fixed and whatnot. And the other being the all so glorious rewrite of the same piece of software where everything that went wrong in A is now great and shiny (right…).

So time goes by and at some point for whatever reason, we deem the rewrite a success. We decide to retire the legacy software. However we would like to keep it's history (just in case, you know…) while at the same time getting rid of the need for two repositories.

Let's say Repository A looks like this:

```
      A---B---C 
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H---I master (A)
```

And coincidentally Repository B looks like this:

```
      S---R---Q
     /         \
K---L---M---N---O---P master (B)
```

So, all we would love to do is type

```
[~/repo-a]$ git magic
```

and get this as a result:

```
      A---B---C               S---R---Q
     /         \             /         \
D---E---F---G---H---I---K---L---M---N---O---P master (A)
```

---

However sadly there is no `git-magic` command (that accomplishes what we want).

What I tried so far was

a]

Looking at the man page of `git-rebase` the merge strategy `ours` seems to be what we wanted

> ours
>
> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the
>   merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring
>   all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to
>   supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is
>   different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy.

```
[~/repo-a]$ git remote add shiny-rewrite git@github.com/orga/shiny-rewrite.git
[~/repo-a]$ git fetch shiny-rewrite
[~/repo-a]$ git checkout shiny-rewrite/master
[~/repo-a]$ git checkout -b shiny-master
[~/repo-a]$ git rebase -s ours master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Already applied: 0001 initial commit
Already applied: 0002 blablabla
Already applied: 0003 …
Already applied: 0004 ZOMG IT'S READY
All done.
```

However now all the commits from shiny-rewrite are gone. Not exactly what we wanted.

b]

The "brute-force" alternative

```
[~/repo-a]$ git rm -r *
[~/repo-a]$ git commit -am "DELETE ALL THE THINGS"
[~/repo-a]$ git remote add shiny-rewrite git@github.com/orga/shiny-rewrite.git
[~/repo-a]$ git fetch shiny-rewrite
[~/repo-a]$ git checkout shiny-rewrite/master
[~/repo-a]$ git checkout -b shiny-master
[~/repo-a]$ git rebase master
[~/repo-a]$ git checkout master
[~/repo-a]$ git merge shiny-master
```

But, now we have the this deletion commit..

```
      A---B---C                  S---R---Q
     /         \                /         \
D---E---F---G---H---I---X---K---L---M---N---O---P master (A)
                       /\
                       ||
             "DELETE ALL THE THINGS"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182560/same-code-different-git-files-merging-with-keeping-history/19183692#19183692

Comment: I'm guessing you figured out you wanted `git merge -s ours` not `git rebase -s ours`?

Answer (score 0):

If you squash X and K after K is inserted, you'll get what you want.

I also made X by cherry-picking K, so that X preserves the committer and date of K when squashing.

```
1) git checkout I
2) git cherry-pick K
3) git rm -rf .
4) # only if there are conflicts in (2):
   git commit
   # only if there are no conflicts in (2):
   git commit --amend
5) git cherry-pick K  # yes, again
6) git rebase -i HEAD~2
7) # edit the file, changing the second commit in the list to a squash
8) # remove one of the duplicated commit messages
9) git rebase --onto HEAD --root P
```

Step 3 is what converts X to an empty commit, preserving everything.